# Почему восклицательный (вопросительный) знак меняет пунктуацию при оформлении прямой речи?

Tags: прямая-речь

Согласно **[правилу Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=159#pp159)**, предложение с прямой  речью имеет такие **варианты** постановки знаков:

(1) Запятая закрывает **придаточное** предложение с **повествовательной** прямой речью:

*Даже когда думаешь: **"Этого просто не может быть",** стоит проверить, так ли это.*

(2) Вместо запятой ставится **тире**, если прямая речь **восклицательная**:

*Даже когда думаешь: **"Этого просто не может быть!"** — стоит проверить, так ли это.*

Какой **смысл** имеет такая замена, на чем основано **это правило**?

**Дополнительный вопрос:**

Можно ли так **изменить** это предложение, чтобы поставить **и запятую,  и тире?**

Comment: И запятая, и тире может быть, если она разделяет реплики. В § 51 об этом написано.

Comment: Так измените, please)

Comment: В смысле, вопрос дополнить?

Comment: Какой ответ? У меня же это вопрос.  Я про эту тему.